# program received signal sigabrt in Ipad program

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, presentmodalviewcontroller

I fix all warnings and now I have such error in my AppDelegate Class

.h file is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UYLAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISplitViewController *splitViewController;

@end
```

.m file is

```
#import "UYLAppDelegate.h"
#import "UYLMasterViewController.h"
#import "UYLDetailViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UYLAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize splitViewController = _splitViewController;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_splitViewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIView *rootView = [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] view];
    rootView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    rootView.layer.cornerRadius =5.0f;
    rootView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
    rootView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5, 0);

    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController; //error here
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

in this row I take an error

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController; //error here
```

SplitViewController consist of 2 controllers, .h file are:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class UYLDetailViewController;

@interface UYLMasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UYLDetailViewController *detailViewController;

@end
```

and the second

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UYLModalViewController.h"

@class UYLMasterViewController;

@interface UYLDetailViewController : UIViewController <UYLModalViewControllerDelegate>{
    UIBarButtonItem *_MessageButton;
    NSInteger modalViewShowType;
}

-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender;

@property (retain, nonatomic, getter=_MessageButton) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *someMessageButton;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *detailItem;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailTitle;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL masterIsVisible;

@end
```

edit:
there is all I see in console

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug 15 16:03:10 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 8217.
Pending breakpoint 1 - ""UYLDetailViewController.m":117" resolved
Pending breakpoint 2 - ""UYLModalViewController.m":30" resolved
Pending breakpoint 3 - ""UYLModalViewController.m":41" resolved
Pending breakpoint 4 - ""UYLDetailViewController.m":63" resolved
Pending breakpoint 5 - ""UYLMasterViewController.m":46" resolved
Pending breakpoint 7 - ""UYLDetailViewController.m":36" resolved
No breakpoint number 7.
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

Please help me to understand it =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some `SIGABRT` errors most of the time, it just means that it can't find that instance you are referring to. So look at that line again and think what might not be declared right.

I think it might help if you change it to.
`self.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;`

Comment: I read about it, but I checked all outlets in my code.                  self.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;
it didn't help

Comment: I find a mistake. It happens becouse I have some problen with my XCode. If I edit the same file in standart editor and in assistant editor the give me differetnt files =(. Do you see such problem?

Comment: try Cleaning your project or Restart your computer. If it's a problem with Xcode then you can't do much about it, but I am sure the problem will go away.